# How to generate a rtl.css file for themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, localization

I'm developing a theme and would like it to support RTL languages. I'd like to automatically generate a partial RTL file, that is, with only the relevant selectors flipped, but every tool I've tried generates a full conversion of the style.css file.

Apparently, the following online tool generates partial RTL files, but it fails when encountering comments/media queries in the original file:

http://rtl.daskhat.ir/

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of [https://rtl.daskhat.ir](https://rtl.daskhat.ir) . can you provide an example of  CSS code, which failed to convert, I can fix it.Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why, but now your tool is doing the conversion correctly. Just a suggestion, could you add a checkbox to maintain or not the comments of the original file? Thanks!!

Comment: currently, I can't do this because the original css completely parse and regenerate again.